# File naming conventions in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Recently, I have started learning ReactJS. The only thing that confuses me is naming **folders** and **files** in the React app directory.

- To name component files, some people follow `TitleCase.js` and some follow `camelCase.js`.
- To name app directories, few people follow `camelCase` and few
  `smallcase` or `small-case`.

I tried to find the official documentation on naming conventions but couldn't. Can someone help me find the right way of naming files in ReactJS?

Comment: there is nothing called perfect or best way of naming files, its totally upto you, but you can follow this: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react

Comment: if you are not using jsx then what you are using ? you can follow those conventions, they are basically for reactjs.

Comment: As said above, there is no "correct" way of doing this. However, since components are essentially always written in `TitleCase` in code, I don't see why not also for the files. Because then you import like `import Component from './Component'`. As for folders, I think the norm is `smallcase`.

Comment: TitleCase for component files is best because it allows you to know other camelCase files are exporting something else than a component.

Comment: React is not opinionated on this. Use what works best for you. As most of us use npm based projects, we tend to follow normal npm guidelines on the structure. Also you get reminders from tools like git and vscode which prefer lowercase names over mixed cases. So any choices come from a result of the other stuff, not React.

Comment: This certainly seems to be one of those opinion-based decisions whose solutions are invariably "pick one and be consistent". My choice of Pascal Case file naming was informed by my decision to use a VS Code extension called ES7 React/Redux/React-Native/JS snippets. One of the React component snippets called rcc automatically creates a common component code snippet with the name case-sensitively auto-created based on the name of the file. So in order to have the component name in the code follow the standard Pascal Case convention, the filename had to be CamcelCase too.

Answer (score 115):

Regarding naming conventions, ReactJS is **unopinionated**.

There isn't an official guideline or statement about the questions you raised. You won't find them in the documentation either.

It's a personal (team) preference. If you struggle to enforce one, you could stick to something like [Airbnb's mostly reasonable approach to React and JSX](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react).

PS: As long as you're consistent, I would say you're safe.

Comment: Here's some more [unofficial guidance](https://gist.github.com/koistya/d7a507438c741ee6adb5) which might be useful:

Comment: Just so future visitors don't have to scroll to find the correct section among Airbnb conventions, here it is: [Naming](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#naming)

Comment: To add to this, folder structure guide focusing redux-toolkit pattern. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-folder-structure/

Answer (score 42):

Based on '[Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#file-name)'

> File names must be all lowercase and may include underscores (_) or
>   dashes (-), but no additional punctuation. Follow the convention that
>   your project uses. Filenames’ extension must be .js.

Comment: This is what I've been doing for the past 2 years and happy with it. I didn't know the Google style guide contained this. It will help me convince teammates :)

Comment: But react component seems like using .jsx as the file extension.

Comment: `.tsx` for TypeScript.

Comment: I'm deeply torn that Google/Angular conventions conflict with React on something as trivial as file naming. ‍♂️

Answer (score 27):

I recommend `hyphens-case` for file naming because all npm modules is `hyphens-case` so when imported custom file is same as npm modules.

Answer (score 16):

As others have mentioned, we adopted the Airbnb style guide. Here is the specific section in their docs about naming conventions:

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#naming

**tl;dr** PascalCase for naming

Comment: i'd like to know why is everyone now calling PascalCasing TitleCasing? is it some millenial-tiktok-thing?

Comment: I imagine it's because no one knows what "Pascal" is any more, and "Title Case" actually means something in the non-computer world.

Comment: @caio-wilson Pascal casing and title casing are different see [Camel case on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) vs [Title case on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case)

Comment: I call it `UpperCamelCase` and `lowerCamelCase`

Answer (score 11):

Based on their docs about [File Structure](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html) I'd opt in for PascalCase as long as it's not `index.css`, `index.html` or `index.js`. Moreover, the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) has this kind of structure, which you can see [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using small letters for filename, because some environment is case sensitive while some are not. Furthermore, it is easier to miss casing mistake.

I just faced an issue deploying my react code to Netlify because of the filename casing issue. For more detailed explanation, you may refer to [Netlify's support guide "Netlify app builds locally but fails on deploy (case sensitivity)"](https://community.netlify.com/t/support-guide-netlify-app-builds-locally-but-fails-on-deploy-case-sensitivity/10754).

Answer (score 4):

I use **PascalCase** for components and classes, even if you use function to create a component you still you pascal case.

### Examples:

- **components folder: PascalCase.jsx**    *my custom components*
- **pages folder: PascalCase.js** *components that represent my page*
- **classes folder: PascalCase.js**
- **others folders: camelCase.js**

never use **snake_case.js**.

For folders i only use lower case, i never used: camelCase, snake_case or hyphen-case.

Comment: e.g.: I need a component, which will contain 2 columns of equal widths 6 and 6
Grid 6 6. 
Without a snake or hyphen case, it will be not readable.

Answer (score 1):

According to Eloquent Javascript. Classes follow TitleCase, and method / functions and properties follow camelCase. It is also said directories and components follow all lowercase naming. It is just preferred way of naming and popular or convention in so many programming languages including C, C++, and Java.

However, Javascript is a wild language and there is no exact rule to follow for naming, and there is only preference. As long as naming is easily readable and consistent in entire module/component/project and it does not confuse other developers, and it is totally up to you how to name them.

Comment: "PascalCase" or "UpperCamelCase". Title case doesn't capitalize all first letters--only those which would be capitalized in a book title, for example. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case.

Answer (score 0):

React is a lot of things but *straight-forward* is not one of them.

But if anything was to be said, I've found this article [5 Best Practices For React Developers](https://www.educative.io/blog/best-practices-react-developer#5) to be very helpful **in my opinion**.

The ones stated regarding naming convention are 2 points:

1. Components should be PascalCase
2. Methods should be in camelCase and be named for their function

Besides that, it's all up to you or the team working on the project because at the end of the day you are the ones who will have to remember everything when the time for making changes or adding updates comes.

Comment: HI, thanks but the question is all about file naming conventions but not Class, Functions, and Variables inside a file.

Answer (score 0):

In a large project, I would like to manage my file in that way. Including the word **component** in the file name is seen like unnecessary, as it's already clear from the file extension that it's a component. But, as your project grow larger, it makes easy to differentiate the files.

```
 src
   components
     addTodo
         addTodoForm.component.jsx
         addTodoFormSubmited.component.jsx
         index.js
     navbar
     todolist
       index.js
   pages
       addTodo.jsx
       index.js
       todo.jsx
       updateTodo.jsx
```

According to that way. I say, i easy to understanding which file is used to **component** and which file is **page**.