# Naming Best Practices for React Components and Functions Including Filenames

Tags: reactjs

I notice that a lot of projects name their react components with uppercase class names and lowercase filenames. Why would that be different?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973199/file-naming-conventions-in-reactjs

Comment: Thanks @Yossi  Google's style guide says "files must always start with lowercase" and react classes when used as components should be uppercase it seems.  Is it reasonable to assume that the standard most people follow is filename starts with lower and class name starts with upper? seems odd and webstorm tooling does not play well with that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe that would not be the best practice. The filename should be the same as the React component's, and should be written in **PascalCase**.

For instance: `Navigation.jsx` exports `Navigation`

**Further reading about naming conventions:**

- [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973199/file-naming-conventions-in-reactjs)

**Bonus:** Structuring files and folders in a React project:

- [Yay, Hackernoon again!](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-structure-your-react-app-98c48e102aad)
- [Alexis Mangin's post](https://medium.com/@alexmngn/how-to-better-organize-your-react-applications-2fd3ea1920f1)
- You probably don't need to read this if you don't use redux, but it has a good comparison between *function-first* and *feature-first* grouping techniques. [Alex Moldovan's post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be)

**Edit:** From [nextjs official website](https://nextjs.org/)

> Next.js will serve each file in `/pages` under a pathname matching the
> filename.
>
> For example, `/pages/about.js` is served at `site.com/about`.

Therefore in case of Nextjs, they wanted to separate component and page files as page files are used for routing.

Comment: I basically agree with @BrianLe but what befuddles me is the NextJS guys dont' follow it and no doubt they are some of the smartest JavaScript folks on the planet. Here is an example:  https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-react-i18next/pages/page2.js

Comment: Are you talking about line 2 `import Link from 'next/link'`

Comment: no @BrianLe. I'm talking about the filename is "page2.js" and the component is defined as "const Page2"

Comment: @Pete remember this is considered 'best practice', but it's totally up to the development team to choose what they want. I don't have much experience in Next.js so I'm not really sure why they did that

Comment: You can also check out other well-known React packages, the majority of them use PascalCase for their files' names

Comment: Thanks. I'm just confused on the consistency and am assuming they are very smart guys and have some logic. I posted on the chat which is kind of hit and miss.  https://spectrum.chat/?t=daab933e-e236-4e2b-987e-935f90416335

Comment: @Pete I read your chat on spectrum and I believe that there is no significant difference. Again, it depends on the development team

Comment: @Pete ah I see. They probably wanted to separate component and page files. That's why they used PascalCase for their component files and lowercase for page files

Comment: I heard back from the next.js team and the reason their /pages components are not PascalCase is the filename is also used as the url and PascalCase would be bad for routing.  (to those 4 that downvoted this question, I hope you feel very powerful in your ability influence)

Comment: Saw the discussion. That’s exactly what I told you up there :)

Comment: Thanks @BrianLe  I missed your connection to page names and urls. Apprecaite the help.

Comment: Hackernoon link is broken

Answer (score 5):

I think is that the same as all javascript frameworks, that should be

- Presentational and Container components are kept at src/components
  Group components by module/feature.
- Keep generic components inside src/components/UI Keep screens simple,
  with minimum structure and code.
- List item Group screens accordingly to route
  definition. For a route /user/list we would have a screen located at
  /src/screens/User/List.jsx.

something like this Finally, our application would be structured like that

[image]

here is a valuable resource to take as [reference](https://hackernoon.com/structuring-projects-and-naming-components-in-react-1261b6e18d76)

---