# super expression must either be null or a function?? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I am trying out react and its my first attempt but it kept saying "TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function"

The code doesn't look problematic to me, could someone help me out? Thanks

**form.js**

```
import React, { component } from "react";

class forma extends component {
  render() {
    return <h2>What's your name?</h2>;
  }
}
export default forma;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Forma extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h2>What's your name?</h2>;
    }
}
export default Forma;
```

- `component` need to be `Component` (it's a named export)
- React component names needs to be in [CamelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973199/file-naming-conventions-in-reactjs)
- Also [read](https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/react-best-practices/)