# What's the purpose of <div className="App"> in a React class render function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new to React, and so far I understand that className in React jsx can be a reference to an html class defined in an imported css file. Like `className="warning"` in the following example, which makes the text display red instead of the default black.

But I'm also seeing, in numerous tutorial examples, elements like `<div className="App">` appearing at the top of the render() function. This typically doesn't reference anything in the imported css file, yet it can often be present even if there is no imported css file in the example at all.

Indeed I find that if I replace it with just `<div>`, the example renders exactly as before. So what do elements like `<div className="App">` do, and what are they for?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1 className="warning">Wakeup World!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.warning {
    color: red
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is just a convention, it does not pertain to React's internal rendering logic or anything like that.

To answer your question about *why* they are there, its for global styling changes that are a little more specific than `html` or `body`. Again, a convention that you can feel free to ignore.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html and related docs

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `<div className="App">` is nothing else but rendering a `<div>` using `App` as the class. If there's no styling linked to that className, you'd get the same result when changing it.

Since React [has no official naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973199/file-naming-conventions-in-reactjs/43979817), there isn't any official document that says that the first element **must** be a `<div>` containing the class `App`

I guess this has become some sort of [unspoken rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspoken_rule#:%7E:text=Unwritten%20rules%20(synonyms%3A%20Unspoken%20rules,action%20implied%20by%20tacit%20assumptions.).

Even Facebooks [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) uses `App` as the first element. ([Source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/85ab02ba583f88ad8aeb04c3dd057778a08f885f/packages/cra-template/template/src/App.js))

However, React's [tic-tac-toe tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#wrapping-up) **doesn't** use the `App` as first element, rather just a `<div className="Game">` as it would make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

**Render div with class "App"**

```
return (
         <div className="App">
           <h1 className="warning">Wakeup World!</h1>
         </div>
       )
```

**Render h1 with class "warning"**

```
return (
         <>
           <h1 className="warning">Wakeup World!</h1>
         </>
       )
```

or

```
return (
           <h1 className="warning">Wakeup World!</h1>
       )
```

This is the syntax of JSX, similar to html and renders what you ask. The examples use the default autogenerated template with `.., but this is not at all necessary