# Show Already included file name, when import a file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My program runs very well but VSCode gives this error. Any solution?
[image: Already included file name]

I am importing `Header` or `Footer`; these are located in root of layout folder directory. But it show:

> Already included file name
> 'd:/Work/gunox/src/components/layout/Footer.js' differs from file name
> 'd:/Work/gunox/src/components/Layout/Footer.js' only in casing.   The
> file is in the program because:
> Imported via "./Footer" from file 'd:/Work/gunox/src/components/layout/Layout.js'
> Root file specified for compilationts(1261)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't speak to the exact error, but it looks like you have a folder called `Layout` in the same folder as another folder called `layout` (ie, they differ only in the capital or lowercase "L"). I'd recommend avoiding this in general and forever when you're building software - it's only going to cause problems and never add any benefit.

Comment: Now, what I do?

Comment: I'd recommend reorganizing your code to avoid this pattern. Maybe this answer (and the link to the AirBNB style guide) will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979817/15038439